# Get child from field via reflection

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

So i have a class like this

```
class Fragment{
   private val binding: MyFragmentBinding
}
```

`MyFragmentBinding` has a private field "webView", which I want to access.

First step:

```
val firstField = fragment.javaClass.getDeclaredField("binding")
```

This works and I got a field with my binding class. But in this class I want to access the field with the name "webView".
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the referenced object, and then repeat the whole process for the field in that object.

```
val binding = fragment.javaClass.getDeclaredField("binding").get(fragment)
val webView = binding.javaClass.getDeclaredField("webView").get(binding)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing link. I additionally had to set `binding.isAccessible=true` and then use `binding.javaclass.superclass.getDeclaredField("webView")` to access the field as it seems to be in the superclass of the autogenerated binding class.